# Will I get the Walked The Path achievement if I complete a New Game+ playthrough on Death March?

Tags: achievements, the-witcher-3

I changed the difficulty several times during my first playthrough. If I start a New Game+ from said playthrough and did not change the difficulty from Death March, then finish the game, would I get the achievement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! I unlocked this achievement while playing NG+